# PHP doesn't read the second $_GET variable after rewriterule regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Here are my rewriterules

My links look like 3.5 or 1.0.0.315  3.05 etc

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?[^a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1 [NC,L]
```

And below my links should be like 3.5&items 3.5&champions 1.0.0.315&items etc.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?[^a-zA-Z]+)&([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1&tab=$2 [NC,L]
```

I do get $_GET['Patch_No'] as I'm supposed to but I do not get $_GET['tab'] this variable is never set for some reason.

So it works fine when it is like

```
^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z]+)$
```

But it doesn't match with 3.5 it works only with numbers like 3.05 3.26 1.0.0.125 etc. but I needed it to work with 3.5 so I added

```
^([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?[^a-zA-Z]+)
```

It works fine for the first RewriteRule That I posted above but it doesn't work for the second one with tab variable

And here also is var_dump($_GET);

```
array (size=2)
  'Patch_No' => string '3.5' (length=3)
  'tab' => string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see.

1. Your links have to look like what you want to pass as varaiables. If you want to pass two variables then your links should look like `/3.05/items` or `1.0.0.315/champions`
2. Rewrite rules don't understand what "etc" means. They are very precise. Either they match the regex or they don't. So you have to be specific about what you want them to do when creating them.

These are the rules you are looking for

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+).([0-9]+)$    index.php?Patch_No=$1    [NC,L,QSA] # allows two sets of numbers
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+).([0-9]+)&([A-Za-z]+))$    index.php?Patch_No=$1    [NC,L,QSA] # allows two sets of numbers & text
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)$    index.php?Patch_No=$1    [NC,L,QSA] # allows 4 sets of numbers
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)&([A-Za-z]+)$    index.php?Patch_No=$1    [NC,L,QSA] # allows 4 sets of numbers & text
```

I gave you rules for queries with two sets of digits and four sets of digits because those are the examples you gave us in your question.

However, you can make as many as you want by adding or removing `.([0-9]+)` to the rule.

Comment: I want the links to look like 3.05&items and it works just fine in the code I posted except with 3.5 and my regex has to be precise since I have few other rewrite rules for this file as well